# Which tour companies have a full permit to access the Churchill Wildlife Management Area?

Tags: canada, ecotourism, arctic, manitoba, churchill

According to the website of Natural Habitat Adventures ( http://www.nathab.com/polar-bear-tours/classic-polar-bear-expedition/ ): "There are **only two polar bear tour operators** in Churchill with exclusive permits to access the full range of the Churchill Wildlife Management Area (WMA) where the best – and often only – polar bear observation occurs"

One of these tour operators is Natural Habitat Adventures. What's the second one?

Comment: Most likely, it's Frontiers North Adventures, the original buggy operator over there. They provide *exclusive insider access* and *(...) have permits to access areas of the Churchill Wildlife Management Area where only Frontiers North Adventures can go*. The [caption on this photo](https://goo.gl/8jelg1) from management on TripAdvisor also states that they *(...) hold the most permits to provide tours in the Churchill Wildlife Management Area*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to their website, that would be [Frontiers North Adventures](http://www.frontiersnorth.com/our-story/the-fna-experience), they mention their permits on the website (emphasis mine)

> In addition to having **permits to access areas of the Churchill
>   Wildlife Management Area** where only Frontiers North Adventures can go,
>   we are also the only travel company with a license to host guests to
>   stay at Cape Churchill in Wapusk National Park.

It's also in their [brochure](https://view.publitas.com/frontiers-north-adventures/frontiers-north-adventures-2016-brochure) (p6, 9, 32)

> [...] we also hold the most permits to operate on the trail network in the
>   Churchill Wildlife Management Area